# How can I make email address unique in python using sqlite3

Tags: python, database, sqlite, email

as you can see in this code I have imported my pyqt5 .ui file and I take inputs from users. then when I want to insert it inside the table that I have created using sqlite3, I want the email address to be unique and for that, I wanna check all the rows and find where the email address equals the input I got from the user. if yes then it will show a message. But the code is not working. `conn.execute("select * from users where email=?", str(email))`, this the part where I wanna check if I have the same email address inside the database or not and the problem is here it ain't working.

```py
def signup(self):
    conn = sqlite3.connect("inventory.bd")
    conn.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users(
                        id integer primary key AUTOINCREMENT,
                        username text not null,
                        email text not null unique,
                        password text not null
                        )''')

    username = self.lineEdit.text()
    email = self.lineEdit_3.text()
    password = self.lineEdit_2.text()
    confirm_pass = self.lineEdit_4.text()

    res = conn.execute("select * from users where email=?", str(email))

    if username == "" or email == "" or password == "":
        QMessageBox.about(Dialog,"warning","Please make sure that you have filled all the information")
        #QMessageBox.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Ok | QMessageBox.Cancel)
    elif (len(res.fetchall())>0):
        QMessageBox.about(Dialog, "warning", "The email you have entered has already been used")
    elif password != confirm_pass:
        QMessageBox.about(Dialog, "warning", "The password does not match!")
    else:
        conn.execute("insert into users(username,email,password) values(?, ?, ?)", (username, email, password))
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()
        QMessageBox.about(Dialog,'welcome','Your account has been created successfully')
```

Comment: Although your project uses PyQt5 that does not imply that your problems depend on that technology, in your case PyQt5 has already done its job: obtain and display information to the user. So your problem has nothing to do with that technology.

Comment: as I know `execute` needs list/tuple with arguments even if you have only one argument - `(email, )` <- see comma inside `()` to create tuple with one element. BTW: you don't have to convert it to string.

Comment: BTW: what means "code is not working."? Do you get error message? always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: @eyllanesc okay, thank you.

Comment: @furas thanks a lot I tired this : res = conn.execute("select * from users where email='%s'" % email). and it worked lemme try the comma thing. it showed an error about the arguments. I am new here. next time I will try to put the error messages whenever I faced any problem.

Comment: @furas I tired to (email,) the argument with a comma and it worked too. Thank you very much.

Comment: using `"%s" % email` is not preferred because it doesn't escape data and it can be used by hackers to steal data (ie. by adding new admin when `email` will be `" ; INSERT INTO users ....  ; "`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of :

```
res = conn.execute("select * from users where email=?", str(email))
```

Try this style of formatting :

```
res = conn.execute("select * from users where email=%s", email)
```

Works very well with database queries....

**Theory :**
Python uses C-style string formatting to create new, formatted strings. The "%" operator is used to format a set of variables enclosed in a "tuple" (a fixed size list), together with a format string, which contains normal text together with "argument specifiers", special symbols like "%s" and "%d".

Here are some basic argument specifiers you should know:

%s - String (or any object with a string representation, like numbers)

%d - Integers

%f - Floating point numbers

Comment: Hi, 
thank youu Satish it really helped. I changed it to: 
res = conn.execute("select * from users where email='%s'" % email)
and it finally worked.